# Delphi 7 and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, delphi-7, dbexpress

How can i connect an **SQLite** Database with **Delphi 7** with **dbexpress**?
When i choose DB2Connection there cames an "Failure rto connect:Unable to load db2cli.dll" Error.

Is it possible to use Delphi 7 and SQLite?

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Good luck with that. I tried some years ago, when Delphi7 was somehow more supported, and I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Thanks. I found a way. Its not a perfect Solution but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access SQLite Database with Delphi 7.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/
use; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNAoU3FykpA

Answer (score 0):

To connect from Delphi 7 to SQLite using the dbExpress driver, you need to find a dbExpress Driver for SQLite.